# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7a83ccb988: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer

Tags: android, ssl, retrofit2, okhttp

strange issue here: when connecting to enpoint i receive this error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7a23be5d48: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@202117037@20.21.17 (120400-316502805):6)
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@202117037@20.21.17 (120400-316502805):16)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.kt:367)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.kt:325)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:197)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:249)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:108)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:76)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:245)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:96)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
        at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.kt:152)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:197)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:502)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

with 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.7.1' and 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'

The problem is that with same configuration, same endpoint but different project everything works.

What could be causing this?  Tried also to add tls 1.2 and 1.3 but doesnt change

**EDIT 23/06/2020**

I compared the two projects and the most importart difference i see is that the class that perform connectTls is different.
The one project that works uses `com.android.org.conscrypt` while the one that's not working is using `com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt` ?

Hope this will help anyone ring a bell also will ask gms teams

Comment: Take a look at what cipher suites and TLS versions the server supports on SSL labs. Make sure your OkHttp connection spec has something from that set.

Comment: @JesseWilson thanks for the response. i'm going to check. i also update the question with new observation

Comment: On GMS, see this: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider

Comment: oh, ok! i'll take a look at it, thanks